# Table displaying the percentages of chosen responses for a vingette (male then female)

Tags: response, spss

People in my study have completed a questionnaire. One of the questions involves the participant reading a scenario/vingette and then they are asked to 'identify the problem' in the scenario. They are then presented with a 9 options (multiple response question).

In my data file men and women are coded numerically. I am currently trying to create a table with the percentage of responses to each of the 9 options for men in one column (adding to 100%), and women in the other (100%).

I know this is probably quite simple, but I've completely forgotten! Any help in exactly how to carry this out in SPSS?

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use the `MULT RESPONSE GROUPS` Command with the `/BASE=RESPONSES` option.

```
*** Create some example fake data.

INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 15.
  LOOP #g = 1 TO 2.
    COMPUTE Gender = #g.
     DO REPEAT response = r1 TO r9.
       COMPUTE response = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(0,2)).
     END REPEAT.
     END CASE.
  END LOOP.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.

FORMATS Gender r1 TO r9 (F1.0).
VALUE LABELS Gender 
 1 'Male'
 2 'Female'.
EXECUTE.
```

And that's how the command looks like with the example data:

```
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$responses (r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 (1)) 
  /VARIABLES=Gender(1 2) 
  /TABLES=$responses BY Gender
  /BASE=RESPONSES
  /CELLS=COLUMN.
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can get what you want from the `CROSSTABS` procedure, see example below and image it produces with my default settings.

```
*Example fake data.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 15.
  LOOP #g = 1 TO 2.
    COMPUTE Gender = #g.
    COMPUTE Response = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,10)).
    END CASE.
  END LOOP.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
FORMATS Gender Response (F1.0).
VALUE LABELS Gender 
 1 'Male'
 2 'Female'.

*Table.
CROSSTABS TABLE Response BY GENDER /CELLS=COL.
```

[image: Crosstabs Table Image]